# define input_size by myself when I apply transfer learning in my own datasets

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, transfer

I'm using tensorflow for deep learning.

I want to try transfer learning in my own datasets, and I downloaded the inceptionv3 model from tensorflow's website. I also find a demo, but I find the model input_size is 299 * 299 *3. I want to define the input_size by myself. Because Keras's inception v3 model can define input_size by myself. Such as the input_size is 512 * 512 * 3.

I don't use the resize function.

I tried to do the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LINPt.png)

but I got the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbRGE.png)

When I change it to be 299 * 299 * 3, the code runs normally.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could actually copy-paste the error messages into your question instead of taking screenshots. Plus, it makes it easier for people who might have this issue in the future to google it.

Comment: Sorry for that. This is my first time asking a question.

Comment: I know :). That's why I'm giving the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily change the input size of a trained model. The trained model's weights only know how to process input of this size. If you want to use pre-trained weights, your best option is to resize your images to the expected size.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But for keras, You can easiily change the input size for the pretrained model.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

As far as InceptionV3 is considered, you can use any image size and tensorflow's preprocessing will take of the image size. Tensorflow's official inception module includes https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/inception/inception/image_processing.py in which you can specify the size of the image that you want to use. The model then can be retrained use this new size.